# Kotlin-allopen plugin + @JvmField on a val not final enough

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-allopen

I am testing a new `kotlin-allopen` and `kotlin-spring` plugins under Kotlin `1.0.6`.

In one of my `@Transactional`-annotated classes I have a field:

```
@JvmField val foo = null
```

When I try to build the project, I get:

`Error:(45, 5) Kotlin: JvmField can only be applied to final property`

Is there any proper way of dealing with this? My real-life code needed `@JvmField` because of the JUnit's `@Rule`. Managed to "solve" the problem by removing a `@JvmField` and annotating a getter instead. Not sure if a bug or a feature.

Comment: I see you submitted a bug in tracker, so it should be here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15541

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the official solution.

In such case, *finality* provided by `val` is not enough. It turns out you need explicitly add `final` keyword there and this is not considered a bug.

```
@JvmField final val foo = null
```

Comment: How is this not a bug? If we put the compiler aside, it's a but in the IDE at least because the message is not clear enough. I had no IDEA (pun intended) what to do with it. For normal JUnit tests it works fine, but for Spring (for example) it throws an error...

Comment: I meant to say "*bug* in the IDE", lol. Anyway, I'm following the issue now. Thanks!